# jquery widgets, _raise event not behaving as expected

Tags: knockout.js, jquery

I'm trying to create a widget that I can use with Knockout.js

I've taken the jquery demo widget for this example from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/):

My code is in a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6W9AY/)

What I am trying to do is to bind to a custom event within the object:

```
    this._trigger("random", event, colors)
```

so in my knockout binding I have this code:

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "random", function (event) {
            alert("Got to here");
        });
```

I expected the alert to fire when the trigger is fired, but it doesn't occur.

However if instead I bind to click.colorize as in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6W9AY/1/) modified code then the alert does fire.

Can anyone explain why the triggered event isn't picked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the widget's eventPrefix - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6W9AY/3/)

```
 widgetEventPrefix: "color",
```

and then raise the event as before:

```
 this._trigger("foo");
```

catching it as follows:

```
 ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "colorfoo", function (event) {
        alert("Got to here");
```

Note the concatenation of "color" and "foo".